# fontspec-example.tex on texlive 2010 and Ubuntu?

Tags: texlive, fontspec

I try to run [fontspec-example.tex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/) through `xelatex` on my Ubuntu 10.10 installation, combined with texlive 2010.

The package cannot find any of the fonts, e.g., TeX Gyre Pagella (error is that
kpathsea does not like the font having a space in its name). What do I do wrong? 
(I do have /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre on my system.)

I tried using the tips in this question: [What fonts are installed on my box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-fonts-are-installed-on-my-box), but I am not sure I understand how to use the font names obtained there.

Comment: The linked question only talks about Type 1 fonts, not OpenType fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(From [Finding a font for XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/finding-a-font-for-xetex/11889#11889)):
Fonts that are installed with your TeX distribution (like the TeX Gyre fonts; look in `.../texmf-dist/fonts`) need to be called with their file name (in XeTeX; LuaTeX accepts the font name). For example,

```
\setmainfont[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont= *-regular,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic]{texgyretermes}
```

See also the “Font selection” chapter in the fontspec manual (`texdoc fontspec`).

Comment: @Caramidr: thanks. This helps. Do you know if there is a way to translate the file name to a font name? Also, I noticed that .ttf are a bit different in that you can use `Comic Sans MS` as the font name, even though the file name is different.

Comment: @Yossi: When you double click on a font file in the file manager, a font previewer will open and (amongst other things) display the font name.