# Font not available despite being installed

Tags: fonts, xetex

I have TeX Live installation at `~/texlive/2014`.

I installed Lato font package using `tlmgr`. There are now several `.ttf` files in `~/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/lato/`

But when I try compiling a file that contains:

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
```

using `xelatex` it gives an error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Lato
/home/user/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for Lato.
/home/user/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Lato
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf Lato
! I can't find file `Lato'.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Lato

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Lato

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: Lato.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Lato' failed to make Lato.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Lato" cannot be found.
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Are you using XeTeX or LuaTeX? LuaTeX will find the font by name, but for the texmf tree you'll need to use the file name for XeTeX. (See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/finding-a-font-for-xetex/11889.)

Comment: @JosephWright I am using xelatex to compile the document. I will edit the question to add this info.

Comment: In that case, I suspect this question is a dupe either of the one I mention or (if we have it) a more general one about `.ttf` fonts and XeTeX.

Comment: @JosephWright perfect. Compiling with Lualatex solved the problem. Please give your comments in the answer form so I can accept it.